# Lumen: Exception Handler - Not catching QueryException or PDOException

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, exception, lumen

I am trying to ensure that exceptions thrown from database connection issues are handled globally.

I have added the following in my app\Exceptions\Handler.php in the render() method, however none of the exceptions are being caught:

```
<?php

namespace App\Exceptions;

use Exception;
use Illuminate\Database\QueryException;
use Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException;
use Illuminate\Auth\Access\AuthorizationException;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException;
use Laravel\Lumen\Exceptions\Handler as ExceptionHandler;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException;
use PDOException;

class Handler extends ExceptionHandler
{
    /**
     * A list of the exception types that should not be reported.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $dontReport = [
        AuthorizationException::class,
        HttpException::class,
        ModelNotFoundException::class,
        ValidationException::class,
    ];

    /**
     * Report or log an exception.
     *
     * This is a great spot to send exceptions to Sentry, Bugsnag, etc.
     *
     * @param  \Exception  $e
     * @return void
     */
    public function report(Exception $e)
    {
        parent::report($e);
    }

    /**
     * Render an exception into an HTTP response.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Exception  $e
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function render($request, Exception $e)
    {
        if ($e instanceof AuthorizationException) {
            return response()->json((['status' => 403, 'message' => 'Insufficient privileges to perform this action']), 403);
        }

        if ($e instanceof MethodNotAllowedHttpException) {
            return response()->json((['status' => 405, 'message' => 'Method Not Allowed']), 405);
        }

        if ($e instanceof NotFoundHttpException) {
            return response()->json((['status' => 404, 'message' => 'The requested resource was not found']), 404);
        }

        if ($e instanceof QueryException) {
            return response()->json((['id' => 0, 'status_billing' => 'The requested resource was not found']), 500);
        }

        if ($e instanceof PDOException) {
            return response()->json((['id' => 0, 'status_billing' => 'The requested resource was not found']), 500);
        }


        return parent::render($request, $e);
    }
}
```

This was also added to my app.php:

```
$app->singleton( App\Exceptions\Handler::class );
```

For the life of me I cant get this to work.

Any help/advice would be greatly appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the below line from your app.php

```
$app->singleton( App\Exceptions\Handler::class );
```

to:

```
$app->singleton(
    Illuminate\Contracts\Debug\ExceptionHandler::class,
    App\Exceptions\Handler::class
);
```

**EDIT**

The reason why the interface is required in the above exception handler binding is, when an exception is thrown while processing a Route, the below function is invoked to process that exception.

```
protected function handleException($passable, Exception $e)
    {
        if (! $this->container->bound(ExceptionHandler::class) || ! $passable instanceof Request) {
            throw $e;
        }

        $handler = $this->container->make(ExceptionHandler::class);

        $handler->report($e);

        return $handler->render($passable, $e);
    }
```

The if condition checks whether or not the container has a binding for the ExceptionHandler class. And if there is a binding, then the exception will be passed on to that exception handler class to be further handled. If there is no binding declared, then the exception will be re-thrown. Here the binding is checked for `Illuminate\Contracts\Debug\ExceptionHandler`. That's why when you directly bind using `App\Exceptions\Handler::class`, the exception is not caught by your exception handler.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.

I did that before seeing this and it worked, but i am unsure why as I had it in from the start and it wasn't working.

Just few minutes ago i decided to put it back and it started working.

Another thing is, and i hope you can verify, if the exception is already caught in the method, then the render wont catch it, correct?

And also, if possible, would you be able to just give me a brief summary of why 'Illuminate\Contracts\Debug\ExceptionHandler::class' is required?

Appreciate it

Comment: Yes, if the exception is already caught in the method, then the render method wont catch it. I have updated my answer to include detailed explanation.

Comment: Awesome, thanks a lot.

Is there any other binds that can be used other than?:
    Illuminate\Contracts\Debug\ExceptionHandler